# SUM of multiple divs that are alpha numeric mixed

Tags: jquery, html, sum, alpha, numeric

I have a collection of divs belonging to the same class and they have a value of ( X1 ), ( X2 ),...
I want to add their numeric value only, like 1 + 2 +.... These divs will be created dynamically so I won't know how many there will be. How can I do that? I have tried the following and it won't work. How can I separate the "(", "X" and ")" from the number and add the numbers together?

```
<div class="test"> ( X1 )</div>
<div class="test"> ( X2 )</div>
<div class="test"> ( X3 )</div>`

$(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('div.test').each(function(){
        sum += parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10)
    })
    $('#sumPlace').text(sum);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the text of each element back, removing anything that isn't a number, and converting the strings to numbers.
That gets you an array of numbers, which can be added up with `Array.reduce`

```
var sum = $('div.test').map(function() {
    return +$(this).text().replace(/\D/g,'');
}).get().reduce(function(a, b) { 
    return a + b; 
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var sum = 0;
$('div.test').each(function(){
    sum += parseInt(this.innerHTML.replace(/\D/g,'').trim(), 10)
})
$('#sumPlace').text(sum);
```

```js
$(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('div.test').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt(this.innerHTML.replace(/\D/g, '').trim(), 10)
  })
  $('#sumPlace').text(sum);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">( 5 )</div>
<div class="test">( 10 )</div>
<div class="test">( 55 )</div>`

<div id="sumPlace"></div>
```